# How to create a microservice-ready monolithic app?

Tags: design, architecture, microservices

After reading the pros and cons of both camps, the consensus I gather is that, go monolith first then microservice only if you really need to. But then those transitioning from an already big monolith are often struggling.

That said, if you're starting something from scratch, what are ways to design a monolithic app so that it's microservice-ready?

Comment: The [Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/) is a good guideline for both monolithic apps and microservice apps. They aren't really opposites. In many regards, a well-done monolith is kind of like a microservice system with only a single type of service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could split your application in "bounded contexts" (see Domain Driven Design) and use events to communicate between contexts. The events should only use simple data types that could be easily transferred over the wire later. Direct object references to another bounded countext wouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what @deamon said do your vertical slices all the way to the database, don't use referential integrity, use Guids as primary keys, use fields and not entities...

Maybe this can help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4s7ioADuCA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxjrObdWQow

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: `use Guids as primary keys` is this a literal primary key? Or just a secondary key to the real auto-incremented primary key of a table? If it's really the primary key, what do you use for sorting? Something like date_created field?

Comment: Yes, Guids as literally primary keys, and yes you can sort by date if you need to get the latest but that is a whole separate discussion :-)